# How to know if a plot is already been called in R

Tags: r, plot, graph, plotly

I got this error when trying to plot a graph with plotly:  `plot.new has not been called yet` Here is how I plot my graph:

```
Age <-c(69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183)
Pertubation <- c(0.002967936,-0.794788368,-1.561544673,-2.938300977,-2.956057282,-3.724813586,-3.84656989,-4.000326195,-3.491082499,-3.705838803,-3.008595108,-3.439351412,-2.518107716,-2.108864021,-1.892620325,-2.175376629,-2.547132934,-2.694889238,-3.985645543,-2.702401847,-3.203158151,-3.238914456,-2.60867076,-2.564427064,-3.254183369,-1.973939673,-0.731695977,-0.625452282,-0.966208586,-0.811964891,-0.018721195,0.320522501,-0.227233804,-0.046990108,-0.820746412,-0.846502717,1.067740979,1.470984675,1.00222837,0.448472066,1.139715762,1.275959457,0.989203153,0.904446848,0.607690544,0.20693424,1.084177935,1.114421631,0.625665327,0.292909022,-0.833847282,-2.208603586,-3.397359891,-4.339116195,-4.950872499,-5.518628804,-6.992385108,-7.023141413,-8.193897717,-8.580654021,-9.428410326,-10.92316663,-11.37392293,-12.21167924,-12.77643554,-13.14219185,-13.67394815,-14.19370446,-14.16046076,-15.29121706,-16.06197337,-16.11472967,-16.29348598,-17.62424228,-17.79699859,-19.42675489,-19.6625112,-20.3642675,-21.4460238,-22.05378011,-23.87553641,-24.06129272,-25.00604902,-25.80180533,-26.77656163,-27.40431793,-28.86407424,-29.45483054,-29.37758685,-30.48534315,-30.07209946,-29.86985576,-29.82561207,-30.46936837,-30.56412467,-30.24788098,-29.40463728,-29.76939359,-29.11314989,-29.0989062,-29.2466625,-29.1654188,-29.28217511,-29.11493141,-28.44568772,-28.65344402,-28.43520033,-28.71795663,-29.06871293,-29.66546924,-28.39422554,-29.68398185,-29.73973815,-29.34349446,-29.45325076)
temp <- cbind(Age, Pertubation)

Pertubation_graph <- plot_ly(data.frame(temp), x = ~Age, y = ~res,
     cex.main = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.2, axes = F) %>%
    layout(title = paste( "Pig ID:", i, ", Lambda =", lambda, "\nDifference between CFI and TTC"),mtext("Percentage of difference: CFI - TTC (%)", side=4, line = 3, cex = 1.2, col= "blue"), plot_bgcolor = "fffff", xaxis = list(title = 'Age (d)'),
                    yaxis = list(title = 'Amount of difference: CFI - TTC (kg)'),type = "p", pch = 10, cex = 0.5,
                    ylim = c(min(B$dif.CFI, res), max(B$dif.CFI, res)), cex.main = 1.5, cex.lab = 1.2, axes = F)
Pertubation_graph <- Pertubation_graph %>%  layout(axis(1, at= seq(dif$eval_day[1],dif$eval_day[length(dif$eval_day)], by = 5), cex.axis = 1.1),
              axis(2, at=, cex.axis = 1.1),
              axis(4, at=, cex.axis = 1.1, col.axis = "blue", col = "blue"),
              abline(crit1,0, col = "red", lty = 2) ,
              abline(0,0, col = "red"))

saveWidget(ggplotly(Pertubation_graph), file=paste0("C:/Users/Kevin Le/PycharmProjects/Pig Data Black Box/Graphs/Step3_graphs/", idc, ".", ID[idc], ".html"))
```

I am using the plotly library and saved it in HTML format. The error occurs at this break point: `axis(1, at= seq(dif$eval_day[1],dif$eval_day[length(dif$eval_day)], by = 5), cex.axis = 1.1)`. I did some research and it seems that the plot has never been called. This however seem strange to me since I already called it as `Pertubation_graph` using `plot_ly`.

I hope anyone can help me out on how to get rid of this issue.
I case where the dataset in the code section does not work, here is [the data file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12inZaLJjTlwBoXKzWZDuwZDmPY36Vw6oKEAxM5KvCNc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: `axis` and `abline` are functions that work only in base R graphics. You cannot use them in plotly.

Comment: @AllanCameron So what is the alternative option? I only want to plot a range between `seq(dif$eval_day[1],dif$eval_day[length(dif$eval_day)]` and also other make up that I put below it.

Comment: @LamTùng check out https://plotly.com/r/figure-labels/ for all the axis options in plotly

Comment: @AllanCameron I have resolved the axis issue, but there is a new issue appears. During the time when I save the graph using `saveWidget`, this error appears: `'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)`. I already use the absolute path. Can you help me on this issue?

Comment: Most of this code is not useful for rendering a Plotly graph. You've got base R plotting code here mixed with a few things that actually work with Plotly. That second call for `Pertubation_graph` is all base R plot code; it does not work with Plotly. Since you're calling `plot_ly`, why are you calling `ggplotly`?